# Does the SAPPHIRE 100297-2L Radeon HD 5830 video card support dual monitors?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

Using Windows 7 machine.  I already have two lcd monitors both with DVI connector and I have my computer setup with dual monitors using an NVIDIA Quadro NVS 290 card that has a DMS-59 connector and it works with an adapter cable.

Now I'm thinking about replacing my existing card with this one:
SAPPHIRE 100297-2L Radeon HD 5830 Xtreme 1GB 256-bit GDDR5 PCI Express 2.1 x16 HDCP Ready CrossFireX Support Video Card
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814102946

Does this card support dual monitors?  And if so, do I need some adapter?  Which one?

**UPDATE**

I can confirm that this card works with two monitors.  I have one hooked up via DVI and the other hooked up via the DisplayPort with a DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter.

In fact, although I haven't test it, I think it's supposed to support 3 monitors as long as one of them supports DisplayPort either directly or via an approved adapter.

Comment: This seems to suggest yes: http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/faqs.aspx#how-many-monitors

Comment: I don't know of mainstream discrete video card that **hasn't** supported dual monitors for almost a decade. . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From ComputerLovers' article on [using dual monitor](http://www.computerlover.com/computer-hardware/graphics-card/dual-monitor-graphics-card.php) graphics cards, they RECOMMEND Radeon HD 5830 as a great card for dual monitor support. Based on this article and the fact that most modern cards support dual monitors, I think it can safely be assumed that you will be able to use Dual monitors.

Comment: Thanks but look at the ports: http://www.newegg.com/Product/ImageGallery.aspx?CurImage=14-102-946-Z02&SpinSet=14-102-946-RS&ISList=14-102-946-Z01%2c14-102-946-Z02%2c14-102-946-Z03%2c14-102-946-Z04%2c14-102-946-Z05%2c14-102-946-Z06&S7ImageFlag=1&Item=N82E16814102946&Depa=0&WaterMark=1&Description=SAPPHIRE%20100297-2L%20Radeon%20HD%205830%20Xtreme%201GB%20256-bit%20GDDR5%20PCI%20Express%202.1%20x16%20HDCP%20Ready%20CrossFireX%20Support%20Video%20Card does it need an adapter?

Comment: You can use the DVI port, then get an HDMI to DVI adapter.

Comment: Is there a particular HDMI to DVI adapter that I need?  I just have a regular LCD monitor with DVI input.  There are so many variations of ports now VGA, HDMI, DVI (multiple versions), and DisplayPort that it's a little confusing.  I tried connecting my second monitor using a DisplayPort to DVI adapter but it's not working.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have that knowledge. You could drop by the chat room and ask. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access